# Dynatable.js - generate select dropdown filter from values in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatable

I'm currently using dynatable.js to generate a searchable/sortable table from a JSON file. Sorting and searching is working so far. However, as far as I can tell/find, a select dropdown for filtering must have the options manually created in the HTML of the table. I need to instead generate the options for the filter from the specific column.

Example:

The Gender column should be filter able by male and female. This example is fine to add the options directly in HTML as they will be the only options to exist. However, the 'course'  column will change over time as courses are added and removed and fed to the table via ajax. The filter options for the column should be generated by the available values in the column.

Is this possible with dynatable as a feature? If not (I can't find it anywhere), how can this select dropdown by generated from the array being used to populate the column.